# strategy to fprintf into a file from a buffer but going to a new line after every 100 characters?

Tags: c, printf

Is there any simple function or strategy that will help me `fprintf` onto a file from a buffer that I have while moving to the next line every 100 characters?

Comment: Yes there is, you can write a program using the `fprintf` function for that. Your question is completely unclear, I am sorry.

Comment: `fprintf` returns the number of bytes written. `strlen` tells you the length used in a string buffer. Some arithmetic will tell you how many bytes to write - and where to split the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINE 100

int main(void)
{    
    char str[10000];
    char *ptr = str;
    int size;

    fgets(ptr, sizeof str, stdin);
    do {
        /* write a maximum of 100 chars to file and a trailing new line */
        /* size stores the number of chars written - trailing nl */
        size = fprintf(stdout, "%.*s\n", MAX_LINE, ptr) - 1;
        /* increment the ptr size positions */
        ptr += size;
        /* if (end-of-buffer - size < 100) exit loop */
    } while (size >= MAX_LINE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using the return value of `fpritnff()`, nice! (As long as it is>= 0).

Comment: @Alter Mann I think I understand what you algorithm is doing, Do you mind commenting the do loop for me. I have a bit confused abt that part. Especially the fprintf arguments/ quotation marks.

Comment: @J.Doe, you are welcome,  regarding your doubt, no, `char *ptr = str;` and `char *ptr = &str[0];` are the same (stores the address of the first element in `str`), but using `char *ptr = &str;` you are initializing a `char *` with an expression of type `char (*)[10000]`

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, not really: `fprintf` does not come with an automatic line wrapping facility.

But you can take advantage of `fprintf`'s return value: the number of characters that were written.  Updating a column count, you can output a linefeed every time you go past a certain value. If your `fprintf` chunks are small enough, the can be a good approximation of what you are trying to do.  To properly compute the column count, you must take into account any linefeeds you may output as part of an `fprintf` function call.

Otherwise, you can `snprintf` to a buffer and search for spaces to break the line appropriately or even just break the line arbitrarily at 100 characters.

Another more general solution is to use `popen()` to pipe the output through a utility that would perform the kind of wrapping you want.

Comment: @J.Doe: Can you click on the grey check mark below the answer score to mark it as accepted?